# open map between smooth manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold, open-map

Let $N, M$ be two smooth manifolds and $f: N \rightarrow M$ a smooth immersion.

> (i)-If $f$ is a homeomorphism on its image the $f(N)$. Then $f(N)$ is a submanifold.

> (ii)- If the dimension of $N, M$ are equal, then $f$ is an open mapping.

for (ii) we have :

It suffices to show that $f$ maps "small" enough open sets to open sets. For that, given $p \in M$, let $U$ be a chart around $p$ such that $f$ is locally the identity. That is, $U$ and $V$ are such that the following diagram commutes.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    U @>f>> V\\
    @V \phi V V @VV \psi V\\
    U'\subset \mathbb{R}^n @>>Id> V' \subset \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{CD}

This is a consequence of the local form of immersions (since $\dim M=\dim N$! Otherwise, $Id$ should be replaced by a inclusion). Now, $f(U)=\psi^{-1} \circ Id \circ \phi$, and each one is an open map ($\phi$ and $\psi^{-1}$ by assumption about charts, and $Id$ since it is $Id$).

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @ArcticChar . how we can solve (i) ?

Comment: Please include the definition of submanifold into the question.

Comment: hint for (i): as $f$ is smooth then $f$ is an diffeomorphism, because a differentiable function is locally invertible around a point if and only if it derivative is not zero at this point